# "EnumSpace" - enum inheritance attempt using namespace macro

Tags: c++, enum

**`EnumSpace`**

This file enables the use of a utility I like to call "EnumSpace". This utility is `enum`s and `namespace`s combined together in order to create an entity that acts like an `enum` that is able to inherit and extend an already existing one.

It provides three macros for that purpose:

1. `ENUMSPACE_CREATE`
2. `ENUMSPACE_EXTEND`
3. `ENUMSPACE_END`

`ENUMSPACE_CREATE` should be used to create a new, independent `EnumSpace`. It receives the name you would like to give your `EnumSpace` as an argument.

`ENUMSPACE_EXTEND` should be used to extend an already existing `EnumSpace`. It receives two arguments:

1. The name of the `EnumSpace` you would like to inherit.
2. The name of the new `EnumSpace`.

`ENUMSPACE_END` should be used like a closing bracket to each of the above.

Usage example:

```
#include ".../enumspace.hpp"

ENUMSPACE_CREATE( First )         ONE                 ENUMSPACE_END
ENUMSPACE_EXTEND( First, Second ) TWO,   THREE, FOUR  ENUMSPACE_END
ENUMSPACE_EXTEND( Second, Third ) FIVE,  SIX,   SEVEN ENUMSPACE_END
ENUMSPACE_EXTEND( Third, Fourth ) EIGHT, NINE,  TEN   ENUMSPACE_END

int main()
{
std::cout
<< Fourth::ONE
<< Fourth::TWO
<< Fourth::THREE
<< Fourth::FOUR
<< Fourth::FIVE
<< Fourth::SIX
<< Fourth::SEVEN
<< Fourth::EIGHT
<< Fourth::NINE
<< Fourth::TEN;
}
```

Output:

> ```
> 0 2 3 4 6 7 8 10 11 12
> ```

You probably noticed the inconsistency. The ability to stitch `EnumSpaces` comes with a price: it is impossible to retain a straight streak of numbers *automatically*.

```
[ONE = 0, _last( = 1)]
[_first = _last = 1, 2, 3, 4, _last( = 5)]
[_first = _last = 5, 6, 7, 8, _last( = 9)]
[_first = _last = 9, 10, 11, 12, _last( = 13)]
```

You CAN manually declare the first element you add to be "first" (-> the previous inherited namespace`s "last"):

```
ENUMSPACE_CREATE( First )         ONE                          ENUMSPACE_END
ENUMSPACE_EXTEND( First, Second ) TWO   = _first, THREE, FOUR  ENUMSPACE_END
ENUMSPACE_EXTEND( Second, Third ) FIVE  = _first, SIX,   SEVEN ENUMSPACE_END
ENUMSPACE_EXTEND( Third, Fourth ) EIGHT = _first, NINE,  TEN   ENUMSPACE_END
```

Which will result in:

```
[ONE = 0, _last( = 1)] V  V  V
[_first = _last = 1,  |1, 2, 3,| _last( = 4)]
[_first = _last = 4,  |4, 5, 6,| _last( = 7)]
[_first = _last = 7,  |7, 8, 9,| _last( = 10)]
```

Or in clear output:

> ```
> 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
> ```

Please note that, even though the macro seems to work OK, it relies on behavior I'm not quite sure is defined.

The macro adds a `_first` and `_last` elements to any `EnumSpace` created to facilitate the "stitch" between them.

Now, what would happen when you extend the `EnumSpace` more than once? There would be more than one `_last` for the new `_first` to pick from...

The macro seems to work just fine, and my guess is this happens because whenever the macro asks for the previous `EnumSpace`'s `_last`, it receives the one in the closest scope, which is the latest inherited `EnumSpace`'s. It's rather ambiguous, however, and your compiler might scream at you. Consider yourself warned.

One last note: You'll probably want to prefix your values with something when using this macro so that you can filter the namespaces names that get inherited along out of auto completion.

```
#define ENUMSPACE_CREATE(EnumSpaceName) \
    namespace EnumSpaceName {\
        enum {

#define ENUMSPACE_EXTEND(EnumSpace, NewEnumSpaceName) \
    namespace NewEnumSpaceName {\
        using namespace EnumSpace;\
        enum { _first = EnumSpace::_last,

#define ENUMSPACE_END \
    , _last }; }
```

Will this work? I mean, I tested this. As you can tell by the output provided. But, if something is fundamentally wrong with this, please let me know.

Comment: Can you give an example of when this is useful?

Comment: @LokiAstari Haha... I actually did this mostly out of spite because there are about 7 questions on SO in which people answered to questions along the lines of "Can I inherit enums?" with either "No, you can't" or some verbose monstrosities.

Of course, I found those questions because I was looking for this functionality myself. Trying to extend an enum to provide function status as return type (Success, File not found, etc.).

Comment: It'll probably help if I say that the extension was necessary for class inheritance where the more basic classes provide common statuses/error types and as things go lower there are some more specific things. 
The "deeper" enum values don't need to ride upstream towards the base classes - the extension is simply there to help keep the common types while adding more onto them.

Answer (score 3):

You have already identified that it's inconvenient for users to have a gap in their values.  That's easily remedied by starting the values immediately after the inherited ones:

> ```
>  _first = EnumSpace::_last - 1
> ```

---

A more convenient set of macros would use a variadic argument list to splice the values into the enum, no longer dependent on the user remembering `ENUMSPACE_END`, and always automatically balanced:

```
#define ENUMSPACE_CREATE(EnumSpaceName, ...)    \
    namespace EnumSpaceName {                   \
        enum {                                  \
            __VA_ARGS__,                        \
            _last                               \
        };                                      \
    }

#define ENUMSPACE_EXTEND(BaseSpace, NewSpace, ...)      \
    namespace NewSpace {                                \
        using namespace BaseSpace;                      \
        enum {                                          \
            _first = BaseSpace::_last - 1,              \
            __VA_ARGS__,                                \
            _last                                       \
        };                                              \
    }
```

I think this looks neater where it's used (and it makes Emacs indentation happier than the bare unbraced lists):

```
ENUMSPACE_CREATE(First, ONE)
ENUMSPACE_EXTEND(First, Second, TWO, THREE, FOUR)
ENUMSPACE_EXTEND(Second, Third, FIVE, SIX, SEVEN)
ENUMSPACE_EXTEND(Third, Fourth, EIGHT, NINE, TEN)

#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    using namespace Fourth;
    std::ranges::copy(std::array<int, Fourth::_last>{
            ONE, TWO, THREE, FOUR, FIVE,
            SIX, SEVEN, EIGHT, NINE, TEN
        },
        std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ", "));
}
```

```
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,
```

---

One defect that this improved version doesn't address is that we can't specify the integer type underlying the enum, nor use `enum class`, with these declarations.

Comment: Gotta admit, did NOT expect an answer 7 years later :D

Comment: The question looked lonely with no answers to keep it company - I thought it might like a Christmas present!